# HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 : "{ "data": { "message": "hello" } }"

Tags: java, rest

```
public Object pRequest(String Url, Object requestBody) throws Exception {
Object obj = null;
Object obj = restTemplate.patchForObject(Url, requestBody, Object.class);
System.out.println(obj);
}
```

This above method should print "{ "data": { "message": "hello" } }"

I am passing correct url, requestBody then getting below error, but expected response is coming in the ExceptionBody ("{ "data": { "message": "hello" } }")

HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 : "{ "data": { "message": "hello" } }"
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)

is there anything i can correct to get response to print in console rather get it in ExceptionBody

Comment: It is giving you a 500 error. See this link to the description. 
https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/troubleshoot/runtime/500-internal-server-error-0#:~:text=The%20HTTP%20status%20code%20500,other%20error%20code%20is%20suitable.

Comment: The (remote) server at `Url` didn't respond with a HTTP "Success" (code 200).  Instead it responded with an HTTP "Error" (code 500).  That (remote) server probably has a log that you could inspect to see what its error was.  You'll need it to change that response code to somethign in the 2XX range or clients will not interpret the response as a success.